# Should I override ToString just for logging purposes?

Tags: .net, debugging, logging, log4net, tostring

Recently a coworker asked me to make some improvements to a few of our logs, since he could not figure out a problem because the log was not giving him meaningful information.

The first thing I thought was to print more information about the object using `String.Format` in the `Debug` call directly (we are using log4net at the moment). Immediately, I changed this train of thought to just implementing the `ToString` method on the model and log that instead, since I could log this same class in multiple locations in the code and would like to implement the formatting in one place only.

In the end, this is the current solution: I implemented `ToString` on the offending class and on a child class and proceeded to log the class itself.

After thinking about it a bit though, I wondered if this is the correct approach to this or if there is another, more elegant/correct, way of doing it.

I found a few posts on the matter, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021065/overriding-tostring-for-debugging-and-logs-should-the-string-be-localized) but nothing conclusive enough. I even wondered if using the [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](http://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=jaredpar&y=2011&m=03&d=18&WeblogPostName=debuggerdisplay-attribute-best-practices&GroupKeys=) would be a decent practice: it is intended for debugging purposes, like logging does. Log4net also supports was is called ObjectRenders [that can be used for such purposes](http://codebetter.com/drusellers/2011/12/01/log4net-object-renders/), but I feel this is a bit odd and very specific to log4net.

I feel the question is broad enough to encompass all object oriented languages, but my particular case is .Net. Is there a definitive best practice in in regards to logging and using the `ToString` methods?

Comment: Imho it's fine to use `ToString` for logging or debugging purposes. It makes your life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

I'd stay away from `ToString()`; even though it is a low ceremony way of logging custom information it adds presentation concerns into an object, concerns that are to be consumed by logging. Since logging is a system that is completely detached from what the objects exist for, you are adding a responsibility to an object that already has one. Cue [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violins

From your question you are talking about two classes that need more information; I think that using a `String.Format` in this case would be enough. It's just as simple and quick as the `ToString` method and less dangerous since it isn't exposed to other consumers.

If more classes need to log custom information depending on object types, then perhaps a dedicated mechanism would become necessary. For example a `IInformationExtractorFor<T>` interface for the classes to be logged that would be resolved in a custom appender; the interface and classes wouldn't be tied to log4net so the system could be reused in other loggers. Of course this would only be implemented if the need arises :)

Answer (score 1):

The only important question here is: are there any other contexts in which `ToString()` would be accessed? Is it ever **directly** data-bound on a UI, for example? If not, then `ToString()` is probably just fine, *assuming* that the objects are entirely yours, and are not part of a library that you are exposing to external callers (where they could use it differently to you). There's no need to introduce the complexity of custom debugger displays and custom object renders unless those actually solve a problem that can't be solved in a simpler and more direct fashion.

Comment: The object in question is a model that is indeed potentially exposed to other teams for instance. We use them as parameters for some services, so some other assembly could call the service through it's interface (we use WCF) and they need the model assembly alongside it. The fact that the `ToString` method is public alone already makes me wary of potential pitfalls.

Comment: @juleagon there is a slight risk that it will become an implicit part of the contract - that they rely on it for equality / uniqueness / sorting. Arguably this is their mistake not yours. But you must decide how important that is.